# Problems changing the prefix of a formset in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a question, what happens is that I have a formset and an empty_form (in the same HTML); I have them to do some calculations, **for the empty_form I already managed to extract the ID and do operations but not for the formset**, and that is that my main problem is that they have the different ID, for example for the formset is like this:

```
id_form-0-quantity
```

and for the empty_form it is:

```
id__form-1-quantity (one more underscore)
```

but with that different ID I have to make some changes in JS, which I don't want to do because I'm very new in JS and possibly messing up the code more. **Is there a way to change the formset prefix to look like this: id__form-0-quantity?;**

I used the following line:

```
formset = ParteFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='__form')
```

But absolutely nothing happens

> views

```
def create_Presupuestos(request):
   extra_forms = 1
   ParteFormSet = formset_factory(PresupuestosParteForm, extra=extra_forms, max_num=20)
   presupuestosclientesform=PresupuestosClientesForm(request.POST or None)
   presupuestosvehiculosform=PresupuestosVehiculosForm(request.POST or None)
   presupuestosparteform=PresupuestosParteForm(request.POST or None)
   presupuestosmanoobraform=PresupuestosManoObraForm(request.POST or None)
   presupuestospagosform=PresupuestosPagosForm(request.POST or None)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       formset = ParteFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='__form')
       if formset.is_valid():
           presupuestosclientesform.save()
           return redirect('presupuestos:index')
   else:
       formset = ParteFormSet()
   return render(request,'Presupuestos/new-customer.html',{'presupuestosclientesform':presupuestosclientesform,'presupuestosvehiculosform':presupuestosvehiculosform,'presupuestosparteform':presupuestosparteform,'presupuestosmanoobraform':presupuestosmanoobraform,'presupuestospagosform':presupuestospagosform,'formset':formset})
```

> HTML

```
                                  <table class="table table-bordered table-nowrap align-middle" id="childTable1">
                                                                                <thead class="table-info">
                                                                                  <tr>

                                                                                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                                                                    <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
                                                                                    </thead>
                                                                                <tbody>
                                                                                {{ formset.management_form }}
                                                                                {% for form in formset %}
                                                                                <div class="part-form">
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        {{form.quantity}}
<!--                                                                                      <input type="text" name="parts_quantity" class="form-control input-new-customer-quantity" />-->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        {{form.unit_price}}
<!--                                                                                      <input type="text" name="parts_unit_price" class="form-control input-new-customer-unit-price" />-->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                {% endfor %}

                                                                                </tbody>

                                                                              </table>

                                                                            <div class="part-form table-responsive" id="empty-row">
                                                                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-nowrap align-middle">
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                            
                                                                                            <td>{{formset.empty_form.quantity}}</td>
                                                                                            <td>{{formset.empty_form.unit_price}}</td>
                                                                                            
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                                  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also include the prefix in the case of a GET request, otherwise it will not prefix that form when you load the page for the first time:

```
def create_Presupuestos(request):
   extra_forms = 1
   ParteFormSet = formset_factory(PresupuestosParteForm, extra=extra_forms, max_num=20)
   presupuestosclientesform=PresupuestosClientesForm(request.POST or None)
   presupuestosvehiculosform=PresupuestosVehiculosForm(request.POST or None)
   presupuestosparteform=PresupuestosParteForm(request.POST or None)
   presupuestosmanoobraform=PresupuestosManoObraForm(request.POST or None)
   presupuestospagosform=PresupuestosPagosForm(request.POST or None)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       formset = ParteFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='__form')
       if formset.is_valid():
           presupuestosclientesform.save()
           return redirect('presupuestos:index')
   else:
       # prefix in case of a GET 🖟
       formset = ParteFormSet(prefix='__form')
   return render(request,'Presupuestos/new-customer.html',{'presupuestosclientesform':presupuestosclientesform,'presupuestosvehiculosform':presupuestosvehiculosform,'presupuestosparteform':presupuestosparteform,'presupuestosmanoobraform':presupuestosmanoobraform,'presupuestospagosform':presupuestospagosform,'formset':formset})
```

Comment: @AnaidBracho: No, I don't think so: the prefix is also past to the extra form by the formset.